# setting jLabel text in java throws exception

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am implementing Tic Tac Toe game in Java, but when I run program and press button,
the excpetion occurs because of my click method. Somehow, it seems like JLabel has never been initialized. Why?

```
package piskvorky;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Piskvorky extends JFrame {
    String[] tahy = {"O", "X"};
    int tah = 0;
    JButton[][] buttons;
    JLabel stav;
    int x, y;

    public Piskvorky(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        setTitle("Piskvorky");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(x, y+1));

        JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[x][y];

        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                buttons[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new MyTextListener());
                add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }

        JLabel stav = new JLabel();
        add(stav);

        pack();
    }

    class MyTextListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton kliknute = (JButton) e.getSource();
            setProperties(kliknute);
        }
    };

    private void setProperties(JButton source)
    {
        source.setText(tahy[tah]);
        source.setEnabled(false);
        tah = 1-tah;
        if(tah == 0)
            stav.setText("Current player: o");
        else
            stav.setText("Current player: x");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Piskvorky(10, 10).setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[x][y]; re-declare field.

Comment: @imx: Ayyyy, he's shadowing more variables than just stav.

Comment: The nullpointer action is 'stav.setText(...)'. You should not re-declare 'stav' field. "JLabel stav = new JLabel();"

Comment: Copy/paste error and exception output rather than paraphrase it.

Answer (score 7):

You're shadowing the stav variable by re-declaring it in the constructor, so yes the stav class field is null.  Solution: sure, initialize stav in the constructor but don't re-declare it there.

Edit: as per imxylz's comment, you're shadowing other variables as well. Time to learn about variable shadowing. Please check the Wikipedia article on this or a Google article as it's an important concept to learn about and to learn how to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

```
JLabel stav = new JLabel();
```

Above line represents as Local Declration. But you are using,

```
stav.setText("Current player: o");
```

in the `setProperties` method. So you are getting a `NPE`. Remove the reclration there and use the `stav` as an instance variable rather than a local variable. It works fine for me after removing the local declaration of `stav`.